# How could I use and manipulate float numbers in PyPanel using textbox widgets instead of sliders?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, user-input, dashboard

**The Problem:** I'm trying to get a float number user input indicator box [like this which I designed on LabView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ksO.png) in Python using PyPanel to eventually make a dashboard with multiple similar boxes (etc.).

**Background:** I'm trying to make a user friendly dashboard using PyPanel. I am new to dashboards but have some experience in running calculations and modelling in Python using Jupyter Notebook.

PyPanel only strictly allows float numbers to be inputted by a user into a
[slider as per this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdI93.png) with code provided below:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
float_slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name='Float Slider', start=0, end=3.141, step=0.01, value=1.57)
float_slider
```

PyPanel also allows a [textbox for strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiYCy.png) but not numbers as seen in the code below:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
x = pn.widgets.TextInput(name='SiO2_[wt%]',value='')
pn.Column(x)
```

Which can then be called on using `display(x.value)` but the output is in a string (i.e. '51.85') which means I cannot do operations with it. When I try;

- multiplying (i.e. `display(x.value*2)`) I get `'51.8551.85'`.
- adding (i.e `display(x.value+2)`) I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26156/2620765455.py in <module>
----> 1 display(x.value+2)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

**The Question:** How can I get a similar user-input widget to [this number textbox that I've originally used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ksO.png) (mentioned in the opening "Problem" statement) using PyPanel to accept user-inputted floating numbers (e.g. 51.85)? Does it involve some manipulation of PyPanel's textbox widget and, if so, what can be done to make basic operations possible from user-inputted numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself a headache and just use the string input and convert str to float with [float()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

Comment: Just putting float(x.value) fixed it thank you a lot!